# Why arity-1 syntax in scala does not compile for self invocation?

Tags: scala

```
object Arity1 extends App{
    def say(something:String) = println(something)

    say ("this works")
    this say "this too"
    say "this shouldn't?"
}
```

The last statement makes sense, what would be the reason for not compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are something called postfix method invocation.

When you write

```
def x(): Int = 1
x toString
```

it is actually the following:

```
def x(): Int = 1
x.toString()
```

As you can see, it has a conflict with your code example, where Scala is looking for a method name, but what you provide it is a String, so Scala complains about that.